# Restrict an APK to work for certain days

Tags: android

I need to make an APK in android,  that should work for only one week if we install that apk in any android devices. Please suggest me how to do this. Thanks in advance

Regards
Anand

Answer (score 0):

1. call a remote REST service that returns a no-go result after 1 week.
2. use the inbuilt android calendar and check for time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't uninstall the application but what you can do is add a broadcast reciever and which will be called from an alarm and inside that broadcast reciever you can block the functioning of the application

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/2651

this link is helpful to set alarm set the alarm to 1 week from now which is

7*24*60*60*1000 milliseconds and it will trigger a broadcast reciever after 1 week you can block the functioning of the code then.